# python pandas non-unique dict keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have an Excel file with data like this

```
Fruits                       Description
oranges                      This is an orange
apples                       This is an apple
oranges                      This is also oranges
plum                         this is a plum
plum                         this is also a plum
grape                        I can make some wine
grape                        make it red
```

I'm turning this into a dictionary using the below code

```
 import pandas as pd
 import xlrd
 file = 'example.xlsx'
 x1 = pd.ExcelFile(file)
 print(x1.sheet_names)
 df1 = x1.parse('Sheet1')
 #print(df1)
 print(df1.set_index('Fruits').T.to_dict('list'))
```

When i execute the above i get the error

```
UserWarning: DataFrame columns are not unique, some columns will be omitted.
```

I want to have a dictionary that looks like the below

```
{'oranges': ['this is an orange', 'this is also oranges'], 'apples':['this is an apple'], 
'plum'['This is a plum', 'this is also a plum'], 'grape'['i can make some wine', 'make it red']}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
df.groupby(['Fruits'])['Description'].apply(list).to_dict()

{'apples': ['This is an apple'],
 'grape': ['make it red', 'I can make some wine'],
 'oranges': ['This is an orange', 'This is also oranges'],
 'plum': ['this is a plum', 'this is also a plum']}
```